# Laravel Pagination Latest Rows (Reversed)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Can't find an example anywhere on how to return latest rows (per the `created_at` column) within pagination?

My current code is:

```
$messages = Message::where('to_id', $user->id)
    ->where('is_read', false)
    ->paginate(10);
```

I want to sort the results by **most recent**. How do I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `latest()` method which is a shortcut to `orderBy('created_at', 'desc')`

```
$messages = Message::where('to_id', $user->id)
    ->where('is_read', false)
    ->latest()
    ->paginate(10);
```

In order to use `->latest()` you must have a column `created_at` in your table.

Comment: How to paginate without where clause and get latest as well ??

Comment: @Farazsalehi That can be `Model::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate()`

Answer (score 11):

Try to orderBy id DESC:

```
$messages = Message::where('to_id', $user->id)
->where('is_read', false)
->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
->paginate(10);
```

Or by created_at:

```
$messages = Message::where('to_id', $user->id)
->where('is_read', false)
->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
->paginate(10);
```

Also you can use `latest()`:

```
$messages = Message::where('to_id', $user->id)
->where('is_read', false)
->latest()
->paginate(10);
```

Comment: This may be faster because id is indexed.